# JavaFX - coloring a shape or label different colors

Tags: javafx, colors, label, background-color, shapes

I have a square label with some text, and I was wondering is there was a way to e.g. color the first 3/4 of the label blue, and the last 1/4 red.

If that's not possible, is it then possible with a rectangle?

```
Label box = new Label();
box.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
box.setPrefWidth(50);
box.setPrefHeight(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a background color with a linear gradient. The best way to do this is in an external CSS file, using the rule

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, blue 75%, red 75%);
```

The format used by the CSS linear-gradient function is described in the [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typepaint).

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColoredLabel extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Some text");
        label.getStyleClass().add("split");
        StackPane root = new StackPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("split-background-label.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the split-background-label.css file

```
.split {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, blue 75%, red 75%);
    -fx-text-fill: white ;
}
```

[image]